# how to have a variable value for casper.repeat

Tags: casperjs

I want to repeat steps with CasperJS depending on a variable value coming from the page where I run CasperJS.

To get this value,  I do something like:

```
casper.waitForSelector(".xxxx", function () {
myvalue = this.evaluate(function() {
        value = Math.ceil(document.querySelector('#yyy').getAttribute('data-all')/10)-1;
        return value;
    });                 
});
```

Then I try to do something like:

```
casper.repeat(myvalue, function() {
```

but it doesn't work because repeat can't find `myvalue` variable. Any idea how to achieve something like that?

EDIT

now I try this :

```
var myvalue = "";                 

casper.waitForSelector(".xxxx", function () {
    myvalue = this.evaluate(function() {
        value = Math.ceil(document.querySelector('#connections').getAttribute('data-num-all')/10)-1;
        return value;
    }); 
});

casper.repeat(myvalue, function() {
```

Now I didn't get any synthax error but the repeat isn't executed at all (myvalue=49)

Comment: Declare _myvalue_ in parent scope of both `waitForSelector` and `repeat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `casper.repeat` and `casper.waitForSelector` are executed asynchronously, so `repeat()` is executed before the `waitFor()`.

Try that :

```js
var myvalue = "";                 

casper.waitForSelector(".xxxx", function () {
    myvalue = this.evaluate(function() {
        value = Math.ceil(document.querySelector('#connections').getAttribute('data-num-all')/10)-1;
        return value;
    }); 
});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.repeat(myvalue, function() {
        this.echo("Here the code to be executed 'myvalue' times");
    });
});
```

The then() statement wait for the previous waitForSelector() to be executed before executing repeat().